# ‘virtual bool QAbstractScrollArea::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)’ is protected

Tags: c++, qt4, qt5, qtwidgets

I tried to find the answer to this one with google but nothing has born fruit. I'm in the process of converting an app from Qt4 to Qt5. This application compiled perfectly in Qt4 but when I try to compile against Qt5 now it's giving me this permission error. Since this class's status is protected in both versions I am having a hard time understanding what I need to change.

This compile issue has been replicated on a few different Ubuntu installs (including wsl) but I haven't tried in Fedora yet.

Here's a subset of the class

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QItemDelegate>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QSize>
#include <qdialog.h>
#include <qcombobox.h>
#include "ui_pegs_page.h"
#include <string>

class EGS_ConfigReader;
class QProcess;
class PEGS_RunOutput;
class QTableWidget;

struct Element {
  int   Z;
  std::string symbol;
 float  aw;
 float  Iev;
 float  rho;
};

const int n_element = 100;

extern Element element_data[];

class TableEventHandler : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TableEventHandler(QTableWidget *parent);
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e);
private:
    QStringList itemCopy;
    QList<QTableWidgetSelectionRange> copyRange;
};
```

Edit:

Here's the method that has issues.

```
TableEventHandler::TableEventHandler(QTableWidget *parent) :
  QObject(parent) {
  if( parent == 0 )
   qFatal("TableEventHandler::TableEventHandler: parent can not be null!");
}


bool TableEventHandler::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e) {
  if( !o ) qWarning("TableEventHandler::eventFilter called with 0 object?");
  if( QString(o->metaObject()->className()) != tr("QTableWidget") ) {
#ifdef EI_DEBUG
      qDebug("Only QTableWidget objects accepted! Returning!");
#endif
      return false;
  }
  QTableWidget *to = (QTableWidget *)o;
  if( e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress ) {
    QKeyEvent *ke = (QKeyEvent*)e;
    if(ke->matches(QKeySequence::Copy) ){
       QString cellText; itemCopy.clear(); copyRange.clear();
       QList<QTableWidgetSelectionRange> ts = to->selectedRanges();
       if(!ts.isEmpty()) {
          for ( int irow = ts.first().topRow(); irow <= ts.first().bottomRow(); irow++){
               for ( int icol = ts.first().leftColumn(); icol <= ts.first().rightColumn(); icol++){
                   QTableWidgetItem *w = to->item(irow,icol);
                   if(w) cellText = w->text();
                   if ( !cellText.isEmpty() ){
                      itemCopy << cellText;
                   }
                   else
                      itemCopy << " ";
               }
          }
          copyRange = ts;
          //cout << itemCopy.join(", ").toLatin1().data() << endl;
       }
       else {
            QTableWidgetItem *w = to->item(to->currentRow(), to->currentColumn());
            if (w) cellText = w->text();
            if ( !cellText.isEmpty() )
                 itemCopy << cellText;
            else itemCopy << "";
       }
       return true;
    }
    else if(ke->matches(QKeySequence::Paste) && !itemCopy.isEmpty() && !copyRange.isEmpty()){
       QList<QTableWidgetSelectionRange> cs = to->selectedRanges();
       int top = cs.first().topRow(), left = cs.first().leftColumn(), icount = 0;
       QTableWidgetSelectionRange ts = QTableWidgetSelectionRange(
                                       top , left,
                                       top  + copyRange.first().rowCount()-1,
                                       left + copyRange.first().columnCount()-1);
       for ( int irow = ts.topRow(); irow <= ts.bottomRow(); irow++){
         for ( int icol = ts.leftColumn(); icol <= ts.rightColumn(); icol++){
             if ( ++icount <= itemCopy.size() )
                to->setItem(irow, icol, new QTableWidgetItem(itemCopy[icount-1]));
                to->setItem(irow, icol, new QTableWidgetItem(itemCopy[icount-1]));
         }
       }
       return true;
    }
    else if(ke->matches(QKeySequence::Cut) ){
       QString cellText; itemCopy.clear(); copyRange.clear();
       QList<QTableWidgetSelectionRange> ts = to->selectedRanges();
       if(!ts.isEmpty()) {
         for (int irow = ts.first().topRow(); irow <= ts.first().bottomRow(); irow++) {
           for(int icol = ts.first().leftColumn(); icol <= ts.first().rightColumn(); icol++) {
               QTableWidgetItem *w = to->item(irow,icol);
               if(w) cellText = w->text();
               if ( !cellText.isEmpty() ){
                  itemCopy << cellText;
               }
               else
                  itemCopy << "";
               to->setItem(irow,icol,0);
           }
         }
         copyRange = ts;
         //cout << itemCopy.join(", ").toLatin1().data() << endl;
       }
       return true;
    }
    else if(ke->matches(QKeySequence::Delete) ){
       QList<QTableWidgetSelectionRange> ts = to->selectedRanges();
       if(!ts.isEmpty()) {
         for (int irow = ts.first().topRow(); irow <= ts.first().bottomRow(); irow++) {
           for(int icol = ts.first().leftColumn(); icol <= ts.first().rightColumn(); icol++) {
               to->setItem(irow,icol,0);
           }
         }
       }
       return true;
    }
    else
        to->eventFilter(o, e);

  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing the protected `QAbstractScrollArea::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)` method either

1. from a method of a class which does not inherit from `QAbstractScrollArea` (**most likely**), or
2. from a method of some other class which is not a friend of `QAbstractScrollArea` (not likely), or
3. from a some function which is not a friend of `QAbstractScrollArea` (not likely).

Note that `TableEventHandler` inherits directly from `QObject` and not from `QAbstractScrollArea`. So in case you're trying to call `QAbstractScrollArea::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)` from one of the methods of `TableEventHandler`, then you get that error.

**EDIT:** Looking at your edited answer, I see that you're calling

```
to->eventFilter(o, e);
```

in `TableEventHandler::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)` where `QTableWidget *to = (QTableWidget *)o;`. The programmer probably meant for `TableEventHandler::eventFilter` not to filter the respective event at that point. The method should then instead just return `false` to pass control to any other event filters installed later on that object.

Comment: I see where you are going with that and will explore. I am wondering how, if it is an inheritance issue this didn't come up in qt4?